# How to authenticate single action with two devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, devise

I have implemented two devise(version: 1.4.8) model in my project for example User and Admin.

Is there any option to configure authentication for single action in same controller with two devise?. example for CartsControler:

```
index, show            -> can access either admin or user
create, update, delete -> can access admin only
```

Currently I have authenticated by calling below method from application_controller.rb

```
def authenticate_user_or_admin!
  unless user_signed_in? or admin_signed_in?
  redirect_to root_url , :flash => {:alert => "You need to sign in as admin/user before continuing..".html_safe }
  end
end
```

in carts_controler.rb

```
class CartsControler < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user_or_admin!, :only => [:index, :show]
  before_filter: :authenticate_admin!, :except => [:index, :show]
```

Is devise providing any default options to authenticate multiple devise models?

Is this proper ways to solve this problem? or any other better solution?